# How long after the expiry date can I use Chipits Skor toffee bits

Tags: baking

The expiry date is 10.2015. Are they ok to use or should I throw them out ?

Answer (score 4):

This is likely a "best by" date, rather than some sort of indication of spoilage.  Usually these dates indicate when the flavor and/or texture is likely to begin to degrade.  Therefore, it is not a health or safety issue, but rather a quality issue.  You can eat them, and determine for yourself whether or not the flavor and/or texture has degraded from the same product consumed before the "best by" or "expiry" date.

Answer (score 3):

The ingredients are:

SUGAR, BUTTER, ALMONDS (ROASTED IN COCOA BUTTER AND/OR SUNFLOWER OIL), MILK CHOCOLATE (SUGAR, COCOA BUTTER, MILK INGREDIENTS, UNSWEETENED CHOCOLATE, LACTOSE, SOY LECITHIN, SALT, ARTIFICIAL FLAVOUR), MILK, SAT.

So, unless the almonds went rancid, nothing can really have happened. The [aw index](https://www.fda.gov/inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/inspection-technical-guides/water-activity-aw-foods)<sup>1</sup> of these is probably close to 0. And sugar is a pretty good conservative. Check how they taste and smell. I assume package is unopened, so no cross contamination is possible.

---

<sup>1</sup> Basically how much water is available for bacteria growth. The drier the food, the safest.